# Likelihood based CI with L2 regularization

Tags: maximum-likelihood, ridge-regression

I apologize if my question seems basic, but I'm attempting to derive confidence intervals for certain parameters whose estimates were obtained through nonlinear least squares regression. Unfortunately, just for some of the system parameters, I had to introduce an L2 regularization term into the cost function. The cost function I minimized is represented as follows:
$$
C(p_1, p_2, \theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(obs_i-pred_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} + \theta^t \cdot \theta.
$$
I am interested in determining confidence intervals for $p_1$ and $p_2$, the parameters not involved in the regularization term.

Now, if the regularization term wasn't there, I would estimate the CI by using the Hessian matrix of the likelihood in the estimates and deriving the covariance matrix using the Cramer-Rao inequality.

Could you please inform me whether, and under what assumptions, I can still employ a similar approach in my current scenario, where regularization is involved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since you are not using Bayesian models you give up the ability to do inference when there is penalization.

Comment: Thank you!, you are right, I am giving up the asymptotic distribution of the MLE, but I saw that there are results also for MLE penalized with Lasso (ref https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/javanmard14a/javanmard14a.pdf). I was wondering if something has been developed also for mixed situations